# Vim custom syntax, excluding previous match highlighting in a region

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a vim syntax highlighting script for a file that uses `*` to denote the start of a comment, except when surrounded by `{}`. i.e.

```
* This is a comment, bellow is math
{ x_variable * y_variable + 10.0 }
```

I would like to highlight only the brackets, and ignore the comment highlighting inside, while still maintaining highlighting for numbers.

So far I have:

```
syn match mathSym "[{}]"
syn region mathRegion start=+{+ send=+}+ contains=numberHi
syn match commentHi "\*.*$" display contains=@Spell

hi link commentHi Comment
hi link mathSym Statement
hi link mathRegion Normal
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. It seem to ignore the `*` as a comment, and provide number highlighting, but no highlighting for the brackets.

I tried

```
region mathRegion start=+{+ send=+}+ contains=numberHi, mathSym
```

but this ends up setting all highlighting in the file to `Normal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing the `numberHi` stuff, but this should do the trick:

```
syn region mathRegion matchgroup=mathSym start=+{+ end=+}+ contains=numberHi,mathSym
syn match commentHi "\*.*$" display contains=@Spell

hi link commentHi Comment
hi link mathSym Statement
```

- Instead of a separate match for `mathSym`, you can use the `matchgroup=mathSym` to highlight the start and end.
- Also, you don't need to link `mathRegion` to `Normal`; just use it for structure.
- The `x * y` won't match inside `mathRegion`, because it isn't contained in here. I don't see any problem with it.

PS: Do you know the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin? It's a great help when writing syntaxes.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. No I didn't know about syntaxattr, I will definitely check that out.